# Can we train a LeNet model on different size images?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

mean that, I have a set of images taken by Canon DSLR and other on mobile camera 12MP . I want to train a LeNet model. Can i use both set as a single dataset

Answer (score 0):

We can only train a CNN model on the same size images. So, you have to resizing images for handle it